# Reportlab elements not being placed in Frames

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm working on creating a script that creates a PDF with a value and qr code created from a value in a json with some extra elements that are for people to capture completion of work. I'm having an issue with getting the elements to be aligned inside each respective frame correctly and have gone through and tried multiple different variations and order of operations including using ChatGPT for ideas on how to fix this.

This my current code (I do have some things commented out while working on just 1 or 2 elements at a time.

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import qrcode
from qrcode.exceptions import DataOverflowError
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, PageTemplate, Frame, Image, Table, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from io import BytesIO
from tqdm import tqdm  # Import tqdm for progress bar
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input', help='input file path', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--StoreId', help='output PDF file path', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def Create_Dataframe():
    args = parse_args()
    df = pd.read_json(args.input)
    entityId = df['entityId']
    row = entityId.str.split('.').str[0]
    rack = entityId.str.split('.').str[1]
    row_num = row.str.split('row').str[1]
    rack_num = rack.str.split('rack|case|table|display|endcap|bin|dispenser').str[1]
    rack_label = row_num + '.' + rack_num
    df = pd.DataFrame({'row/rack': rack_label, 'barcode': entityId})
    return df

def create_qr_code(barcode):
    try:
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data(barcode)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
        img_buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(img_buffer)
        return img_buffer

    except DataOverflowError as e:
        print(f"QR code data is too large: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating QR code: {e}")
        return None

class EmptySquare(Flowable):
    def __init__(self, width, height, border_color=colors.black, fill_color=colors.white, border_width=1):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.border_color = border_color
        self.border_width = border_width
        self.fill_color = fill_color

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.setFillColor(self.fill_color)
        self.canv.setStrokeColor(self.border_color)
        self.canv.setLineWidth(self.border_width)
        self.canv.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height, stroke=1, fill=1)

# Define the EmptySquare instances and text
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styles['Normal']
empty_square1 = EmptySquare(60, 60, border_color=colors.black)
text1 = Paragraph('<font size=48>Calibrated</font>', style)
empty_square2 = EmptySquare(60, 60, border_color=colors.black)
text2 = Paragraph('<font size=48>LCV</font>', style)

def create_pdf(df, output_name):
    try:
        total = len(df['barcode'])

        pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

        with tqdm(total=total) as pbar:
            for barcode, row_rack in zip(df['barcode'], df['row/rack']):
                img_buffer = create_qr_code(barcode)
                if img_buffer:
                    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("temp.pdf", pagesize=landscape(letter))

                    # Create frames for each element
                    # row_rack_frame = Frame(
                    #     x1=30, 
                    #     y1=300, 
                    #     width=730,
                    #     height=280,
                    #     showBoundary=1,
                    #     id='row_rack_frame'
                    # )
                    # qr_frame = Frame(
                    #     x1=0,
                    #     y1=-100,
                    #     width=155,
                    #     height=155,
                    #     showBoundary=1,
                    #     id='qr_frame'
                    # )
                    row_rack_frame = Frame(
                        inch/2,
                        inch*4.5,
                        inch*10,
                        inch*3.75,
                        bottomPadding=inch,
                        topPadding=0,
                        showBoundary=1,
                        id='row_rack_frame'
                    )
                    qr_frame = Frame(
                        inch*4.5,
                        inch*1.75,
                        inch*2.5,
                        inch*2.5,
                        showBoundary=1,
                        id='qr_frame'
                    )
                    # calibrate_frame = Frame(
                    #     x1=0,
                    #     y1=0,
                    #     width=250,
                    #     height=80,
                    #     showBoundary=1,
                    #     id='calibrate_frame'
                    # )
                
                    # lcv_frame = Frame(
                    #     x1=0,
                    #     y1=0,
                    #     width=250,
                    #     height=80,
                    #     showBoundary=1,
                    #     id='lcv_frame'
                    # )
                    

                    # Add Frames and Create Template
                    page_template = PageTemplate(id='page', frames=[row_rack_frame,qr_frame])
                    doc.addPageTemplates([page_template])

                    story = []

                    # Add "row/rack" text to row_rack_frame
                    #row_rack_html = '<para><font size=280>{}</font></para>'.format(row_rack)
                    row_rack_style = ParagraphStyle(name='row_rack', alignment=1, leading=50, fontSize=280, spaceAfter=50, spaceBefore=0)
                    row_rack_paragraph = Paragraph(row_rack, style=row_rack_style)

                    
                    # Set QR Code
                    img = Image(img_buffer, width=150, height=150)

                    # Create table for calibrate text and square
                    cal_data = [
                        [text1, empty_square1]
                    ]
                    
                    # Create a table for lcv text and square
                    lcv_data = [
                        [text2, empty_square2]
                    ]


                    # Set Calibrate Table size
                    cal_table = Table(cal_data, colWidths=[250, 60], rowHeights=[60], vAlign=2)

                    # Set LCV Table size
                    lcv_table = Table(lcv_data, colWidths=[150, 60], rowHeights=[60], vAlign=2)

                    # Append data to frames
                    story.append(row_rack_paragraph)
                    story.append(img)
                    story.append(cal_table)
                    story.append(lcv_table)
                    

                    doc.build(story)
                    pdf_writer.add_page(PdfReader(open("temp.pdf", "rb")).pages[0])

                pbar.update(1)

        # Write the merged PDF
        pdf_writer.write(open(output_name, "wb"))

        print(f'PDF file "{output_name}" created successfully.')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating the PDF: {str(e)}")

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    df = Create_Dataframe()
    output_name = args.StoreId + '.pdf'  # Use StoreId as the output file name
    create_pdf(df, output_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The json input that is pulled looks like the following `"entityId":"row1.rack1.fv"`
The paragraph text is the split version of the row/rack and the QR code is the full version

This is what the current output looks like
[image: current output]

And this is what I'm looking to make it look like (just now with a QR instead of a Barcode and the colors don't matter)
[image: Ideal output]

I'm also having an issue with the "empty_sqaure" that is being placed in the cal_table and lcv_table where it's not vertically aligning with the text.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Spacer with minus values before image for example:

```
story.append(Spacer(0,-50))
story.append(img)
story.append(cal_table)
```